# Can't get output of assembly language code

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, masm

I am newbie in assembly language. I am trying to get a string of numbers from user terminated by <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the length of the string reaching 20. When I executed the program it didn't show any error, but neither did it show any output nor did it terminate when the string exceeded the 20 characters limit.

My code is:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
    var1 db 100 dup('$')
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov dx, ax
mov si, offset var1

l1:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
cmp al,20
je programend
mov [si], al
inc si
jmp l1

programend:
mov dx,offset var1
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov ax, @data
> mov dx, ax
> ```

You want to initialize the `DS` segment register here but have erroneously written `DX`. Honest typo, but your code will have corrupted the Program Segment Prefix in this manner.

> I am trying to get a string of numbers from user terminated by ENTER key or the length of string reaches 20

It's clear that you need a loop to do this and that **you will need 2 tests to decide about when to stop!**

1. test the character in `AL` to see if it is 13
2. test a counter (e.g. `CX`) to see if it reached 20

```
  xor cx, cx           ; Empty counter
  mov si, offset var1
TheLoop:
  mov ah, 01h          ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int 21h              ; -> AL
  cmp al, 13
  je  programend
  mov [si], al
  inc si
  inc cx
  cmp cx, 20
  jb  TheLoop
programend:
```

But wait, didn't the task say that it had to be a string of numbers? You need to make sure that the input is indeed a number.
Numbers "0" through "9" have ASCII codes 48 through 57.

```
  xor cx, cx           ; Empty counter
  mov si, offset var1
TheLoop:
  mov ah, 01h          ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int 21h              ; -> AL
  cmp al, 13
  je  programend
  cmp al, 48
  jb  TheLoop          ; Not a number
  cmp al, 57
  ja  TheLoop          ; Not a number
  mov [si], al
  inc si
  inc cx
  cmp cx, 20
  jb  TheLoop
programend:
```

Without using a separate counter and using the assembler's ability to translate characters into codes:

```
  mov si, offset var1
TheLoop:
  mov ah, 01h          ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int 21h              ; -> AL
  cmp al, 13
  je  programend
  cmp al, "0"
  jb  TheLoop          ; Not a number
  cmp al, "9"
  ja  TheLoop          ; Not a number
  mov [si], al
  inc si
  cmp si, offset var1 + 20
  jb  TheLoop
programend:
```

Answer (score 2):

See the comments in the code below. Remember not to confuse the data read pair `ds:si` with `dx:si`. One could also argue that `ds:di` would be more appropriate here.

```
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, offset var1
    
    xor cl, cl ; set CX to zero
    
    l1:
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        ; AL now contains the character read
        mov [si], al ; put the character into our variable
        inc si ; move up the memory cursor
        
        inc cl
        cmp cl, 20
        jl l1
        ; if the number of iterations is less than 20,
        ; do all of the above again
        ; otherwise proceed to program end
    
    programEnd:
        mov dx, offset var1
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h
        ; at this point we have printed the string read
        
        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h
        ; and now we've terminated the program

main endp
end main
```

Comment: `xor cl, cl ; set CX to zero` I don't think this comment is true!